# When I compiled thrift, make error : no such subcommand: `fmt`

Tags: rust, gnu-make, thrift

While running this command `/home/hw/.cargo/bin/cargo fmt --all -- --check`, make error :no such subcommand: `fmt`. (I suspect other subcommand not find, too)

I try to update rustfmt and use it in other project successful. But in thrift rust subcomponent is not useable.

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to fix this.

OS:ubuntu 20.04
rustc/cargo 1.40.0
rustup 1.24.2
GNU Make 4.2.1
project https://github.com/apache/thrift

Comment: Is `cmake` tag related to the problem somehow? Note, that CMake and Make are **different** things.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an error related to cargo or the makefile that it's being used in, but 'cargo-fmt' is an additional package that needs to be installed with `rustup component add rustfmt`.  If that doesn't fix your problem, it might be a problem specific to `thrift`

Comment: You may post this on the mailing list as well. There are some Rust devs around.

Comment: See also https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/1331 and some more occurrences. Maybe one of these does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem when trying to install Thrift. When I tried to rethink of it, I found that I didn't use `./bootstrap.sh` at first as the installation says.

After doing that, I can install Thrift successfully~